# Git Config command failing through java. $HOME not set

Tags: java

I am trying to run **git commands** through JAVA. My Linux version is REDHAT 7.3 and git version is 1.8. All the commands are working fine but when I run git config --global user.name "myName" it throws an error

 `fatal : $HOME not set`.

I tried exporting the Home PATH through JAVA by following code :
  export HOME=$HOME:/path/home

But i got the following error:

Cannot run export - execvpe failed (ENOENT - no such file or directory).

Just After running the command I checked the HOME path through `System.getEnv("HOME")` and it was returning me the correct PATH. I tried updating the Git version to **2.22** as well on RHEL but still no use.

In windows,all the commands are working fine but on Linux it throws the error.

Comment: i tried git config --global user.name "name" still the error is same.

Comment: What do you get as a result of the command `System.getEnv("HOME")`?

Comment: It returns me the correct home path. /home/user

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the command be

```
git config user.name "myName"
```

instead of

```
git config --user.name "myName"
```

Comment: i tried using it that way as well as git config --global user.name "name" still the error persists